# Get latest output of a running command

Tags: process, monitoring, proc, output

I have a command running for a long time, which I don't want to disturb. However, I would like to keep check on the process (most of the time remotely). I am constantly monitoring the process via commands like `top`, `iotop`, `stat` etc. The process is a terminal based process which wasn't started via `screen` or `tmux` or similar. So the only way to check the output is using physical access.

I know that `/proc` contains lot of info about the process. So I was wondering if it also can display the output (or even just the last batch of output -- char/word/line). I searched in `/proc/<pid>/fd`, but couldn't find anything useful.

Below is the output of `ls -l /proc/26745/fd/*`

```
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 28 13:19 /proc/26745/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Oct 28 13:19 /proc/26745/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/17
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 Sep 27 22:27 /proc/26745/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/17
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `strace` for that:

```
strace -qfp PID -e trace=write -e write=1,2
```

That will trace all `write(2)` system calls of PID and its child processes, and hexdump the data written to file descriptors 1 and 2.

Of course, that won't let you see what the process has *already* written to the tty, but will start monitoring all writes from a point on.

Also, `strace` is not amenable to change its output format -- you should explore using `gdb(1)` or write a small program using `ptrace(2)` if you need more flexibility.

Comment: As you have rightly pointed out, this command gives all the output (only) **from now on**. To some extent, this serves my partial need. Thanks for introducing me to `strace`!